# ViewPager in MvvmCross 3.0.14

Tags: mvvmcross

I saw examples of using ViewPager in MvvmCross on https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings.
I am using MvvmCross 3.0.14.
In that link which version of MvvmCross is used.?
If I want to use ViewPager in My MvvmCross 3.0.14.,then what changes should I make into that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the history, there has been attempted binding fix with version 3.0.7, but without testing; Have you tried to run it with your project and see what happens?

Comment: Yes,It is working in My MvvmCross 3.0.14 version Android App(level 15).

Comment: Now I want a horizontal sliding tabs,Where can I get its examples?

Comment: Does anyone know where can I find an updated version of 
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings
for MvvmCross 6.2.2? The old one don't work at all in this version and I'm not successful in fixing it.